# Sql insert if row does not exist

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 3 tables called `table1` `table2` and `table3`. the `table3` contains records that have `table1.id` and `table2.id` and some other columns as well. So I need to do the following. for each record in table 1 I need to see if in table3 there is a row containing that table1.id and any other table2.id if there is no such record I want to insert it.

so here is the example.

suppose table1

```
1 ... ... ...
2 ... ... ...
```

table2

```
10 .. .. ..
20 .. .. ..
```

table3

```
1 | 10 .. .. ..
2 | 20 .. .. ..
```

I need to add

`1 20 .. .. ..` and 
`2 10 .. .. ..` rows to the table3 because for `table1.id` 1 it did not have the row which had all `table2.id`s (in this case 20) and for `table1.id` 2 it also did not have the row which had all `table2.id`s (in this case 10) in it. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I've got it right try this:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (Table1_id,Table2_id)
SELECT Tablei.id,Table2.id FROM Table1,Table2
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                          FROM Table3 
                          WHERE Table3.Table1_id=Table1.ID 
                                AND
                                Table3.Table2_id=Table2.ID)
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.Table1_ID = Table1.ID AND Table3.Table2_ID = Table2.ID)
    INSERT INTO Table3(Table1_ID, Table2_ID) VALUES (ID1,ID2)
END IF
```

Comment: Careful - this can result in a race condition

Comment: @JamieMarshall Race Condition?

Comment: @RaahimFareed - if statements are notorious for their locking behavior.  They're not evaluated the same as a single statement such as the accepted answer and the state of the rows being evaluated in the if statement can change before the insert actually happens.  I deal with this all the time.  When you use if to check records you should almost always use an explicit transaction.

Comment: @JamieMarshall Makes sense, also googled on this more, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make a `cross join` and them insert the combinations that do not exist from that cross join.

[**sqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3217/17)

```
insert into table3(col1, col2)
  select t.a, t.b
    from table3
   right join (select table1.col as a, table2.col as b
                 from table1
                cross join table2) t on t.a = table3.col1 and t.b = table3.col2

   where table3.col1 is null
     and table3.col2 is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another syntax would be:

```
INSERT INTO t3 (t1id, t2id ) 
SELECT 
    t1.id
    , t2.id
FROM
    t1,t2
EXCEPT
    SELECT t1id, t2id from t3
```

And furthermore you could add triggers on t1 and t2 to fulfill the task automatically.