# Error with not exists code - mariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'm not sure why:

```
INSERT INTO $db.further_assess (taskid) VALUES ('id')
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $db.further_assess where taskid='$id')
```

is giving me this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT 
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM risk_assessment.further_assess where taskid='222' at line 2
```

was following this: [Sql insert if row does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110532/sql-insert-if-row-does-not-exist)

**Update:**

My, now correct, query:

```
        INSERT INTO $db.further_assess (taskid, reportid)
         SELECT '$id', '$report_id'
         FROM (SELECT 1) as dummytable
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $db.further_assess where taskid='$id');
```

Comment: An INSERT statement has no WHERE clause. What is you goal?

Comment: Insert only if taskid does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An INSERT statement has no WHERE clause. If you want to run a conditional INSERT statement you can use an INSERT-SELECT statement with a dummy table:

```
INSERT INTO $db.further_assess (taskid) 
   SELECT 'id'
   FROM (SELECT 1) as dummytable
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $db.further_assess where taskid='$id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler (and faster) to do

```
INSERT IGNORE  INTO $db.further_assess
    (taskid)
    VALUES
    ('$id')
```